# C++ design choice

Tags: c++, oop

There is a class ActionSelection which has the following method:

ActionBase* SelectAction(Table* table, State* state);

*ActionBase* is an abstract class. Inside of the *SelectAction* method some action is fetched from the *table* considering the *state* if the table is not empty.

If the table is empty, a random action should be created and returned. **However *ActionBase* is an abstract class, so can not be instantiated.**

For different experiments/environments actions are different but have some common behavior (that's why there is an *ActionBase* class)

The problem is that this function (*SelectAction*) should return an experiment specific action, if the table is empty, however it does not know anything about the specific experiment. Are there any design workarounds of this?

Comment: the question was corrected

Comment: Define what are good random actions. Derive a random action from actionbase and make it so that they all register themselves in a linked list. Then your random action is simply the process of taking one from the list which is anyhow accessible because it is a linked list where the first one is static in the class RandomActionBase

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: "question was corrected"... and closed ... while I was writing an aswer :(. Either way, the "normal" action in such a situation is to write an error message/report an error, in such a way that users have the most information to fix the problem (something like "table XXX should contain records matched to specific experiments - table is empty instead)"

Comment: A bunch of people are closing questions for which they don't know the answer. I perfectly get what the op wants.

Comment: ok the question is closed.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I was typing in an answer that explains creating a derived class from actionbase called randomactionbase. Then derive from this class all viable random actions. In randomactions constructor link them all together. A random is then to be taken from the static list.

Comment: alright thanks. it makes sense to create a separate class 'randomactionbase' . Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that you need to create a static instance of each derived randomactionbase in the cpp file that defines a concrete implementation thereof. Otherwise the static list will be empty of course.

Comment: Plop ! Back online. Hope you guys kept your answers at hand.

Comment: @igotca after all my trouble i would have hoped for at least an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether empty tables...

1. Are expected to happen under normal circumstances
2. May happen under abnormal circumstances
3. Should never happen unless there is a bug in the program

#### Solution 1:

Include empty table handling into your control flow. As-is the function does not have enough information to react properly, so either :

- Pass in a third parameter, containing a default action to return :

  ```
  ActionBase *SelectAction(Table *table, State *state, ActionBase *defaultAction);
  ```

  If you don't want to construct the default action unless it's needed, you can pass its type via a template parameter instead, optionally with additional parameters to construct it with :

  ```
  template <class DefaultAction, class... DefActArgs>
  ActionBase *SelectAction(Table *table, State *state, DefActArgs &&... args);
  ```
- Let the caller handle it, by returning whether or not the operation was successful :

  ```
  bool SelectAction(Table *table, State *state, ActionBase *&selectedAction);
  ```

#### Solution 2:

Throw an exception. It will bubble up to whoever can handle it. This is quite rarely used as a parameter check, since it should have been thrown by the object that should have produced a non-empty table in the first place.

```
ActionBase *SelectAction(Table *table, State *state) {
    if(table->empty())
        throw EmptyTableException();

    // ...
}
```

#### Solution 3:

Setup an assertion. If your function received an empty table, something is broken, better halt the program and have a look at it with a debugger.

```
ActionBase *SelectAction(Table *table, State *state) {
    assert(!table->empty());

    // ...
}
```

Comment: upvoted because of the list of 3 possible options. I am assuming option1 in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I had in mind : It is not tested code but you get the idea.
1.

```
//header
class RandomActionBase : public ActionBase{
public
    RandomActionBase();
    static RandomAction* selectRandomAction();
protected:
    static RandomActionBase* _first;
    RandomActionBase* _next;
    void register(RandomActionBase* r);
};

//implementation
RandomActionBase::_first = NULL;

RandomActionBase::RandomActionBase():_next(NULL){
    if (_first==NULL) _first = this;
    else _first->register(this);
}

void RandomActionBase::register(RandomActionBase* r)
{
     if (_next==NULL) _next = r;
     else _next->register(r); 
}

RandomAction* RandomActionBase::selectRandomAction()
{
    //count the number of randomactionbases
    int count = 0;
    RandomActionBase* p = _first;
    while(p){
         ++count;
         p = p->_next;
    }
    //now that you know the count you can create a random number ranging from 0 to count, I 'll leave this up to you and assume the random number is simply 2, 
    unsigned int randomnbr = 2;
    RandomActionBase* p = _first;
    while(randomnbr>0){
        p= p->_next;
        --randomnbr;
    }
    return p;
}

//header
class SomeRandomAction : public RandomActionBase{
public:
   //implement the custom somerandomaction
}

//implementation
static SomeRandomAction SomeRandomAction_l;
```

The idea of course is to create different implementations of SomeRandomAction or even to pass parameters to them via their constructor to make them all distinct. For each instance you create they will appear in the static list.
Extending the list with a new imlementation just means to derive from RandomActionBase , implement it and make sure to create an instance, the base class is never impacted by this which make it even a design according to OCP.
Open closed principle. The code is extendable while not having to change the code that is already in place. OCP is part of SOLID.

2.
Another viable solution is to return a null object. It is quite similar as above but you always return the null object when the list is empty. Mind you a null object is not simply null. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern
It is simply a dummy implementation of a class to avoid having to check for null pointers to make the design more elegant and less susceptible for null pointer dereferencing  errors.